# jquery ajax in spring boot keeps running into error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I'm currently using spring boot, and my ajax function keeps running into error function without any error log.

my view :

```
<div id ="EditModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <form class="modal-dialog" th:action="@{/EditPhoneNumber}" th:object="${phoneNumber}" method="POST" id="PhoneEditForm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" class="hidden" id="edit-modal-phone-number-id" name="id" value=""/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number" id="edit-modal-phone-number-number" name="number" value=""/>
                    <input type="text" class="hidden" id="edit-modal-person-id" name="personID" th:value="${personID}"/>
                    <p id="EditFormError"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="SubmitEdit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#SubmitEdit").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("it ran here");
                var inputID = $("#edit-modal-phone-number-id").val();
                var inputNumber = $("#edit-modal-phone-number-number").val();
                var inputPersonID = $("#edit-modal-person-id").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "/ValidateEditPhoneNumber",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data : JSON.stringify({"id" : inputID, "number" : inputNumber, "personID" : inputPersonID}),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success : function(result){
                        alert("Success "+result.responseText);
                        $("#PhoneEditForm").submit();
                    },
                    error : function(result){
                        alert("Error "+result.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ValidateEditPhoneNumber",method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String ValidatePhoneNumber(@Validated @RequestBody PhoneNumberRequest phoneNumber, BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println(phoneNumber.getId());
    System.out.println(phoneNumber.getNumber());
    System.out.println(phoneNumber.getPersonID());
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "Something happened";
    }
    else return "SUCCESS";
}
```

The string i got from the controller is always "SUCCESS" so i guess the problem isnt in the controller. But what causes the problem?
Please help.

Comment: Try to remove `dataType : "json"` from javascript and see if it works

Comment: okay that worked. thanks o7